# Convert timedelta to decimal [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert `time_delta` to `float` in Pandas:

Main_df

```
date          time_delta 
2019-01-01    01:30:07.502101
2019-01-01    02:00:00.134445
2019-01-01    01:45:02.949292
2019-01-01    00:30:06.393828
```

Ouput_df

```
date          time_delta 
2019-01-01    1.5
2019-01-01    2
2019-01-01    1.75
2019-01-01    0.5
```

This is what I've tried so far but this did not work out for me:

```
def time_to_float(timedelta):
    hrs = timedelta.dt.total_seconds()// 3600
    minute = round(timedelta.dt.total_seconds() % 3600 / 3600,2)
    return float(hrs + minute)

df['timedelta'].apply(time_to_float)
```

Comment: Try `df['time_delta'] = df['time_delta'].dt.seconds/3600` Obviously you can round the result if needed

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df['time_delta'] = (df['time_delta'].dt.total_seconds()/3600).round(2)
```